# Fetching result from core data based on two attributes

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have on entity in my core data model

Entity - "Meesage"
Attributes

1)message (String)

2)read (boolean)

3)date (Date)

4)senderID (String)

How will I get latest message of unique senderIDs?

I am new to using core data..any suggestion what should be NSPredicate r NSSortDescriptor?

Answer (score 0):

Perform a query and get all messages with the required senderID, then sort that array of messages on the date field by using sortUsingSelector function on the array. Then retrieve the  last element of the array if you sort ascending..or the first if you do it descending.

Comment: I don't know senderID. Basically i need to show last message from unique senderIDs.

Comment: oh ok. my bad. There might be ways of doing this with multiple predicates but I've never used them and im not sure how. Another way would be to fetch all messages (provided you dont have a huge number) and then do the processing locally: scan all messages, identify all possible IDs, then perform queries for all IDs like I said in the original answer...sorting the results by date. However im sure this is not the best solution. I just wanted to mention it